# Drawable is causing ResourceNotFound Exception

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-resources

I want to combine 2 vector drawables in `layer-list` but for some reason it is causing `ResourceNotFoundException`. Any suggestions?

```
findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.icon).setImageDrawable(
                    if (isSuccessful) ContextCompat.getDrawable(a, R.drawable.camera_success_icon) else ContextCompat.getDrawable(a, R.drawable.camera_error_icon)
)
```

Here is drawable:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <!--set image to be shown on cicular image view-->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/round_icon_background_blue"/>
    <item android:id="@+id/tintDrawableImg">
        <bitmap android:src="@drawable/checkmark" android:tint="@color/white"/>
    </item>
</layer-list>


Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/camera_success_icon.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f070089
            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie(ResourcesImpl.java:854)
            at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable(ResourcesImpl.java:638)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity(Resources.java:888)
            at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:827)
            at android.content.Context.getDrawable(Context.java:635)
            at androidx.core.content.b.f(ContextCompat.java:2)
```

Comment: Are you sure your file is in drawable folder with the correct spelling that you're using ?

Comment: This type of exception usually occurs when the resource is not present in the mentioned folder.  Make sure to check you have placed both vector files in simple drawable folder and not in drawable-24 or any other folder. Also, verify the file names.

Comment: Yeah it is placed correctly inside drawable folder. I tried to invalidate caches and restart also clear project but its not working.